# Access cookie set in one managed package VF page in another VF page from extension package

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, cookies

I have a base package A which has a VF page abc.vf an extension package B which has a VF page xyz.vf I'm setting a cookie in xyz.vf but it is not accessible by abc.vf in base package A because these two pages run on different instance. Is there a way for me access the cookies from abc.vf I did search documentation but it says nothing. Any is appreciated Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a supported way to do this. You should consider migrating to [Second Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) (2GMP), which allows you to share namespaces between packages. This would give your packages the ability to communicate through such mechanisms directly.